# How do I use a jQuery plugin init options in another method?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Let's say this is the initialization of the plugin:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tree").fname({
                animSpeed: 0
            });
        });
```

Now, I want to call another method and still keep that animSpeed value:

```
$('#tree').fname('expand');
```

However, with my current code, the animSpeed value is lost and the default one is used instead in the expand method call (it works in init).  How could I change this?

Current Code:

```
;(function($){

    $.fn.fname = function(method) {

        var defaults = {
            animSpeed           : 'fast'
        };
        var option = {};

        var methods = {

            init: function(options) {

                option = $.extend(defaults, options);

                return this.each(function() {
                    code...
                });
            },

            expand: function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).children('li').slideDown(option.animSpeed);
                });
            }
        };
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the original options in the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of the elements it is being called on:

```
return this.each(function() {
    $(this).data('fname-options', options);
    // Code...
});
```

so that you can later access it from your other methods:

```
expand: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            options = $this.data('fname-options');

        $this.children('li').slideDown(options.animSpeed);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  I've never used .data() before.  Seems to be a very useful function that I'll have to add to my arsenal.